# What is happening internally when we called any shell commands

Tags: c, shell

Can any one please help me in understanding the code/Steps flow internally when we are calling any shell command. For example suppose I run  the follwoing on bourne shell:

```
ls  -l | grep -r "string"
```

What are the function calls happening internally?

As far as I know it will call some `execv` family functions internally. But can anyone tell me what are the other function call it will make and what will be the sequence of that?

Comment: do you know `pipe` - a kind of IPC **?**

Comment: fork, execv, pipe and dup are about all that are required.

Comment: It is probably very dependent on the implementation so its shell specific. IMO the question is very, very broad. In `*sh` you will have whole mechanism invoked to interpret the query, set-up and environment variables, find the commands to run, etc. Once you get past that, the pipe is fairly simple to implement with standard POSIX/C.

Answer (score 11):

You can take a look yourself at what happens by using the strace utility. Run it with:

```
strace sh -c 'ls  -l | grep -r "string"'
```

This will run a shell that in turn will run your command, and at the end strace will print out what's happening behind the scenes in terms of system calls.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Strace is really very helpfull.

Answer (score 3):

In short:

1. parsing and lexical analysis
2. expansion

   1. brace expansion
   2. tidle expansin
   3. variable expansion
   4. artithmetic and other subrstitutions
   5. word splitting
   6. filename generation/expansion
3. execution

   1. bash fork itself (once for every command)
   2. restore the SIGINT handler to default
   3. opens pipes between commands (dups stdin, stdout)
   4. closes original stdin/stdout
   5. exec each child with the command
   6. parent bash waits...

maybe others will add more precise "steps"...